# App crashes in ios simulator when trying to use Phone auth in react-native firebase

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I've followed the docs and did the necessary settings but the app crashes while launch. I'm not able to figure out the problem as to why this is occurring. any one who worked with rnfirebase? facing this issue?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text, TextInput, Image } from 'react-native';

import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

const successImageUri = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/09/16/12/icon-803718_1280.png';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.unsubscribe = null;
    this.state = {
      user: null,
      message: '',
      codeInput: '',
      phoneNumber: '+44',
      confirmResult: null
    };
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyAvKPtsqqqGjkGLkXD8BeqOR6GwJaI2AcE',
      appId: '1:170852024080:ios:9bb19d2f74715186',
      messagingSenderId: '170852024080',
      projectId: 'chatapp-7c693',
      authDomain: 'chatapp-7c693.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://chatapp-7c693.firebaseio.com',
      storageBucket: 'chatapp-7c693.appspot.com'
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user: user.toJSON() });
      } else {
        // User has been signed out, reset the state
        this.setState({
          user: null,
          message: '',
          codeInput: '',
          phoneNumber: '+44',
          confirmResult: null
        });
      }
    });
  }

//This is the example from the docs, so it must work

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.unsubscribe) this.unsubscribe();
  }

  signIn = () => {
    const { phoneNumber } = this.state;
    this.setState({ message: 'Sending code ...' });

    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
      .then(confirmResult => this.setState({ confirmResult, message: 'Code has been sent!' }))
      .catch(error =>
        this.setState({ message: `Sign In With Phone Number Error: ${error.message}` })
      );
  };

  confirmCode = () => {
    const { codeInput, confirmResult } = this.state;

    if (confirmResult && codeInput.length) {
      confirmResult
        .confirm(codeInput)
        .then(user => {
          this.setState({ message: 'Code Confirmed!' });
        })
        .catch(error => this.setState({ message: `Code Confirm Error: ${error.message}` }));
    }
  };

  signOut = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  };

  renderPhoneNumberInput() {
    const { phoneNumber } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ padding: 25 }}>
        <Text>Enter phone number:</Text>
        <TextInput
          autoFocus
          style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15 }}
          onChangeText={value => this.setState({ phoneNumber: value })}
          placeholder={'Phone number ... '}
          value={phoneNumber}
        />
        <Button title="Sign In" color="green" onPress={this.signIn} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderMessage() {
    const { message } = this.state;

    if (message.length) return null;

    return <Text style={{ padding: 5, backgroundColor: '#000', color: '#fff' }}>{message}</Text>;
  }

  renderVerificationCodeInput() {
    const { codeInput } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ marginTop: 25, padding: 25 }}>
        <Text>Enter verification code below:</Text>
        <TextInput
          autoFocus
          style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15 }}
          onChangeText={value => this.setState({ codeInput: value })}
          placeholder={'Code ... '}
          value={codeInput}
        />
        <Button title="Confirm Code" color="#841584" onPress={this.confirmCode} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { user, confirmResult } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {!user && !confirmResult && this.renderPhoneNumberInput()}

        {this.renderMessage()}

        {!user && confirmResult && this.renderVerificationCodeInput()}

        {user && (
          <View
            style={{
              padding: 15,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              backgroundColor: '#77dd77',
              flex: 1
            }}
          >
            <Image
              source={{ uri: successImageUri }}
              style={{ width: 100, height: 100, marginBottom: 25 }}
            />
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 25 }}>Signed In!</Text>
            <Text>{JSON.stringify(user)}</Text>
            <Button title="Sign Out" color="red" onPress={this.signOut} />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

> can someone help? ive checked the docs again ..but no help ?idk
>   what more details I should add..this is my first question on stack
>   over flow..didnt know it was this annoying to ask a question...
>       I tried the web firebase sdk and can use the anonymous signin.. but I need phone auth which I'm not able to accomplish as it has different setups for ios and android ...rnfirebase is suppose to same as the web sdk

Comment: do you see any error from the logs, please paste it here

Comment: there were no logs..i found the problem, i was using web firebask sdk which needs the .initializeApp() ...After i configured the project to use rnfirebase i didnt need the firebase.initializeApp() as it is being configure in the googlePlist..after i removed that it worked

Comment: awesome, glad it worked.

Answer (score 5):

One of the few tricks will do

**1. Add custom URL schemes to your Xcode project:**

- Open your project configuration: double-click the project name in
  the left tree view. Select your app from the TARGETS section, then
  select the Info tab, and expand the URL Types section.
- Click the + button, and add a URL scheme for your reversed client ID.
  To find this value, open the `GoogleService-Info.plist` configuration
  file, and look for the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` key. Copy the value of that
  key, and paste it into the URL Schemes box on the configuration page.
  Leave the other fields blank.

more info here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating

**2. Run project from xcode then get back to terminal**

Using Xcode, make sure you are opening the workspace file and not the project file. Run the it, once successfully built close Xcode get back to terminal `react-native run-ios`

Comment: i found the problem, i was using web firebask sdk which needs the .initializeApp() ...After i configured the project to use rnfirebase i didnt need the firebase.initializeApp() as it is being configure in the googlePlist..after i removed that it worked

Comment: I have followed the 1. and 2. both steps still below error is coming.  Exception ‘Your app is missing support for the following URL schemes: com.googleusercontent.apps.14xxxxxxx-…’ was thrown while invoking signIn on target RNGoogleSignin with params(2786,2787) callstack:(….