# IOS crashes on Google SignIn React Native Expo 32

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, google-signin

I have a detached app which I recently updated from Expo 31 to Expo 32. In the new version, the Google Sign in has completely changed and I had to redo the code.

The Android version is not working locally (it gives a fail error) but when I upload to the store it works fine. But, the IOS version fail both local and in Store (it crashes the whole app) when I click the Google Login button specifically this line of code `await GoogleSignIn.signInAsync();`

this is how I try to sign-in

```
await GoogleSignIn.initAsync({
    clientId: clientId,
    scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
    behavior: 'web'
});


await GoogleSignIn.askForPlayServicesAsync();
result = await GoogleSignIn.signInAsync();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here =>
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47290909/1840606

I still don't know why it was not creating the `url type` for me and I had to add it manually.